# Java unable to generate add methods from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have this type of array in WSDL file:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Entries">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" 
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xsd:element name="brand" type="xsd:string" 
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xsd:element name="model" type="xsd:string" 
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xsd:element name="engine" type="xsd:string"
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xsd:element name="highway_length" type="xsd:int"
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xsd:element name="city_length" type="xsd:int"
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
                <xsd:element name="fuel_consumed" type="xsd:int"
                minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When I generate server side classes, adders are generated only for brand, model and engine and not for others.

I have tried using xsd:integer type and then adders where generated, but in Java  this type is BigInteger, which is not necessary.

My question is, how should I change my WSDL file in order to make sure that add methods are generated for all elements?

EDIT: This question is still not answered, I just used xsd:Integer types and in Java casted BigIntegers to ints.

Comment: Which libraries are you using to generate the server side classes? Try some other options e.g.: http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/5-techniques-create-web-servic

Comment: @kaykay I am using Axis2 and I can't use other tools since my assignment says so